# Rails got installed successfully in ubuntu, but when i check for version it shows error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

In ubuntu, I successfully installed rails, But when i check back for the version of rails it shows error.
[image]

Comment: can you provide more data?
wich version manager?
wich ruby?

Comment: did you try restarting your terminal after installation?. If you are facing the issue after restarting your terminal, now try restarting your computer. In the mean time share the installation instructions you have followed.